# how to prevent out of range exception when looping through a list

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.5

When using an IList collection, is there anyway to protect against errors like this?

> **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException**: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I have an IList that I define like this:

```
 IList<PlantType> plants
```

It is used in this loop:

```
     while ( plants[position].cellA + HalfLife >= plants[position + 1].CellZ)
     {
         plantName = plantName + ";" + plants[position].Name;
         position++;

     }
```

However, I get the error mentioned above after it tries to continue the loop beyond the length of the list.

After looking at this again, I wonder if it's because of this condition in the while loop:

```
position + 1
```

Because if the loop was already on the last member in the list, and it tried to get the CellZ property of (position + 1), then it would probably generate the error Im seeing.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the indexing for a list starts at 0 but the count for a list just tells you how many are there in the list so a list with 100 items can only go to list[99]. If you try to fetch position >= plants.Count you will get index out of bounds. To solve this you need to add a breaking condition to stop the loop when `position >= plants.Count`:

```
 while (position < plants.Count && plants[position].cellA + HalfLife >= plants[position + 1].CellZ)
 {
     plantName = plantName + ";" + plants[position].Name;
     position++;
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't (position <= plants.Count) be better?  Because it seems with (position < plants.Count), I'd miss the last member in the list.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell keep in mind that the indexing for a list starts at 0 but the count for a list just tells you how elements are there in the list so a list with 100 items can only go to list[99] so if you try to fetch products >= list.count you will still get index out of bounds.

Comment: Oh ok, so position can only goto 99 even if there are 100 elements?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell yup that is correct since your first item is list[0]